# Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServicesBase.dll not in GAC

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I am trying to start a workflow in my SharePoint 2013 provider hosted app.
The class I'm looking for is `WorkflowServicesManager`, however the dll `Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServicesBase.dll` is not in the location I would expect.
Where can I get this dll from?
thanks

Comment: You mean its not on your development workstation? Have you [downloaded and installed the SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30722)?

Comment: Yes I have installed the SDK

Answer (score 2):

You can make a reference to file directly using it's location for Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServicesBase:

> %Windows%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServicesBase\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServicesBase.dll

I aslo wasn't able to get it usual way and had to reference file manually